# Google DBM Python API - filters

Tags: python, google-api, google-python-api

According to the DBM's API reference (https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/v1/queries#resource), it is possible to filter providing an array of filters like:

```
"filters": [
                {
                    "type": "FILTER_ADVERTISER",
                    "value": "my advertiser"
                }
            ],
```

but, I am always getting the report without the filter.

Could someone provide me a example of query with filter? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the filter name is "FILTER_ADVERTISER", instead of "FILTER_ADVERTISER_ID", it actually stands for the advertiser ID.

It is written in the documentation, my bad.